# lock app or software to lock computer on the network

Tags: windows, gratis, windows-7, security, information-management

A software that i can implement on network or individual PC that will allow them to lock after certain period of inactivity but keeps the display on. For example i'm doing a presentation and I end up walking away from my computer for a bit i want the pc to lock but keep whatever that is on the display on.

Comment: So... pull up a confidential doc, walk away, and the doc is visible but keyboard/mouse action is disabled?  Doesn't seem secure.  Under *nix, when the screensaver kicks in there is an option to lock the workstation at that time as well.

Comment: @ ivanivan.....thank you for the response...i understand what you are saying but this is why i gave that scenario...i work for a private school and the teachers often use their computers to present stuff for the students on the overhead projector, and if a student is taking notes of whats been displayed on the screen the teacher cant luck the computer, and sometimes the teaches walks away to attend other students or walks out of the room so i want the computer to luck so it can't be manipulated but at the same time maintain the display for the students.

i hope this makes more sense

Comment: OK... Think I can give you a good answer/work around

Answer (score 1):

OK, the last time I dealt with Windows and such was Workstation 4 and 2k, just edging into XP.  But this should work

First, you need some way of grabbing the screen image every X amount of time, say every 1 minute, and automatically and saving it with a static filename - say, `c:\desktop_screen.png`.  A quick search makes this look promising - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/matthew_van_eerde/2011/11/29/programmatically-grabbing-a-screenshot-of-the-primary-display/

Then simply set the lock screen image and screen saver to be that image.  Apparently it has to be by-user - https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-change-default-lock-screen-image-in-windows-10/

A little more digging around shows that using the Task Scheduler from Win 7 up allows you to create your own timing event, which can include locking the screen...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was doing some more research and came across ClearLock witch seems to do What i am looking for .here is the link if you want to check it out http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Lockdown/ClearLock.shtml